# How to store EACH SINGLE value of a radio button on a page in php to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am new to php and MySQL. I am making a exam app site, where the task is to store all the clicked radio button answers by the user in the database. 
The app does not tell the user the right/wrong answer. It will store whatever and as much times he changes the answer.

For e.g. = if a user A is taking the test and now the user doesn't know the answer to question 2. He may click on option 3 and later option 1. 
My task here is to store in the database option 3 is clicked and later option 1 is clicked. not on the click of submit. Every click on radio buttons must be recorded.

I already have a timer on the webpage. Also I need to keep a track via timestamp.

Is it possible to record all these details? If yes, how will the code run?

eg: my code for  a question is:

```
<h3>Which of the following function is more appropriate for reading in a multi-word string?</h3>
   <br>
   <input type="radio" name="q5ans" id="q5ansA" value="A" />
   <label for="question-5-answers-A">A) scanf()</label>

   <div>
      <input type="radio" name="q5ans" id="q5ansB" value="B" />
      <label for="q5ansB">B) gets()</label></div>

      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="q5ans" id="q5ansC" value="C" />
        <label for="q5ansC">C) printf()</label>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="q5ans" id="q5ansD" value="D" />
        <label for="q5ansD">D) puts()</label>
      </div>
```

I'm currrently using xampp and phpmyadmin. Completely new to all this, kindly help!!!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: so you want to store value when user select radio button or when user submit?

Comment: i want to store the radio button clicked every time by the user.... before and after pressing submit ...all data movements on the page..

Comment: `gets()` should not even be on the list of answers.

Answer (score 0):

With Javascript (not included in this answer) and something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="q5ansList" id="q5ansList" />
```

You could easily keep track of every click, then just read value of `q5ansList`.

If all your answer values are simple like in your question, just use a ',' or a space to separate the clicks.